# How can I iterate two list of maps at once?

Tags: functional-programming, elixir

I have two maps containing a list of maps. How can I filter "customers" map, returning only customers that have a proposal in the proposal list?

```
%{proposals:
    [
        %App.Structs.Proposal{customer_id: "5202845", ...other_fields},
        %App.Structs.Proposal{customer_id: "9778978", ...other_fields}
    ]
}

%{customers: 
    [
        %App.Structs.Customer{id: "5202845", ...other_fields},
        %App.Structs.Customer{id: "5643635", ...other_fields},
        %App.Structs.Customer{id: "9778978", ...other_fields},
        %App.Structs.Customer{id: "3423454", ...other_fields}
    ]
}
```

What I want:

-> Given the list, I'll run a function that will return the name of this customer.

I've tried two "for", filter by ids then compare the two lists, reduce the customer list based in id... None of them worked.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Given that input that you have shown, can you please provide what you want the output of your function to be? I don't quite understand.

Comment: Justin, I just wanna get the agents. Those lists became from different parts of code. I need to relate them.

Comment: agents?  Your question doesn't contain any agents

Comment: SORRY! I've read an article about it. I meant "customers" :P #fail

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way would be to use a comprehension (thanks @keroro520 for the formatted input):

```
proposals = [
  %{customer_id: "5202845", other: "foo"},
  %{customer_id: "9778978", other: "foo"}
]
customers = [
  %{id: "5202845", name: "foo"},
  %{id: "5643635", name: "bar"},
  %{id: "9778978", name: "baz"},
  %{id: "3423454", name: "boo"}
]

for %{customer_id: cid} <- proposals,
    cs <- Enum.filter(customers, & &1.id == cid),
  do: cs.name
#⇒ ["foo", "baz"]
```

I have to say, though, that you are doing it wrong in the first place. The lookup is unavoidably done for each proposal’s `customer_id`, leading to `O(N²)` efficiency, which is generally bad.

The best approach would be probably to convert `proposals` to Ecto schema, with `customers` embedded. The reinvented wheel would look like introducing a `Proposal.new/2` method that will both update the struct itself *and* immediately lookup customers to update the nested `customer_names` field (the same should be done for `Customer` struct to update proposals respectively.) Both could live in `Agent` to maintain their state. Maybe it’s a premature optimization, though.

Comment: The lookup part can be `O(log n)` though by creating a lookup map first, which'll make the whole operation `O(n log n)`. @keroro520's solution does that which is the best you can do in Elixir.

Comment: @Dogbert yes, `O(n log n)` there, I missed it. But as I noticed it’s not the best one can do in Elixir. We are to decide, where we want to pay taxes: on writing/memory or on reading and if writes are rare, we might opt-in for maintaining the embedded structs, making a lookup time linear.

Comment: That doesn't make the whole operation faster than `O(n log n)` though. Also, I realize my statement is not entirely true -- you can do it in linear time using ETS tables, which probably is a premature optimization considering the downsides of creating an ETS table.

Comment: @Dogbert excuse me? If `proposals` struct _already_ contains a consumer’s name, the lookup time would be linear.

Comment: Do you mean lookup will be `O(log n)` (faster than linear)? My point was that the whole operation is still either `O(n log n)` or `O(n^2)` to create `n` structs depending on how you implement "immediately lookup customers to update the nested customer_names field". In either case @keroro520's solution is simpler and as fast or faster.

Comment: @Dogbert no, I mean we could have a slow writes and the fast (`O(N)`) reads, if we opt-in for maintaining `proposals` _storing_ customer’s name.

Answer (score 3):

You could try the code below (However, I think maybe it is better if you change `proposals` and `customers` data structure, for example, use map data structure and `id` as key).

```
customer_ids = Enum.map(proposals, &Map.get(&1, :customer_id))
customers_id_names = Enum.map(customers, &{Map.get(&1, :id), Map.get(&1, :name)})
                  |> Enum.into(%{})
Map.take(customers_id_names, customer_ids)
```

Complete module code: https://gist.github.com/keroro520/61173bda3b1441e8a6be25eb0166c6f8

Comment: I'd recommend posting an Elixir script instead of a module (like https://gist.github.com/7767e965307e590f03c1d313e22a0a70). Your solution is very elegant and just 3 lines long but destructuring/passing the input doubles the line of code and obscures the core solution.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way is to do exactly as you said: `filter "customers" map`

First, we shamelessly copy paste some of the hard work on part of @keroro520:

```
    some_map = %{
    proposals: [
      %{customer_id: "5202845", other: "foo"},
      %{customer_id: "9778978", other: "foo"}
    ],
    customers: [
      %{id: "5202845", name: "foo"},
      %{id: "5643635", name: "bar"},
      %{id: "9778978", name: "baz"},
      %{id: "3423454", name: "boo"}
    ]}
```

Then we start off with singling out the `foreign keys` from `proposals`:

```
proposals = Enum.map(some_map[:proposals], &(&1[:customer_id]))
```

Then we do a simple `filter` over `customers`:

```
filtered_customers = Enum.filter(some_map[:customers], fn %{id: id} -> Enum.member?(proposals, id) end)
```

These are all the `customers` with their full fledged details that have a `proposal` belonging to them. If you only want their names, then map their names accordingly:

```
Enum.map(filtered_customers, &(&1[:name]))
```

And there pops out as your answer:

```
["foo", "baz"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just one other way of doing it, I personally use reduce a lot. (your data structures are also a bit weird and if you're assembling them somewhere you could skip the entire into just by making an "orders" map initially instead of a list - this also doesn't "iterate" two lists at once, but I doubt that's what you want either way)

```
proposals = %{proposals:
    [
        %App.Structs.Proposal{customer_id: "5202845", some: "foo"},
        %App.Structs.Proposal{customer_id: "9778978", some: "baz"}
    ]
}

customers = %{customers: 
    [
        %App.Structs.Customer{id: "5202845", name: "one"},
        %App.Structs.Customer{id: "5643635", name: "two"},
        %App.Structs.Customer{id: "9778978", name: "three"},
        %App.Structs.Customer{id: "3423454", name: "four"}
    ]
}

props = Enum.into(proposals.proposals, %{}, fn(%App.Structs.Proposal{customer_id: ci}) ->
 {ci, true} end)

Enum.reduce(customers.customers, [], fn(%App.Structs.Customer{id: id, name: name}, acc) -> 
case props[id] do
  nil -> acc
  _ -> [name | acc]
end) end)
```

Comment: Consider using two function clauses directly matching `id: nil` and `id: id` in them instead of `case`. Also, `= c` in function clause is redundant and issues the warning.

Comment: The problem with the `nil` matching is it doesn't work since all elements in customers will have id. I thought about adding a `when`, but you can't `Access.*` on guard clauses. `c` is undoubtedly unneeded, and even `p` on the previous `into`, since you only need the key on the map

Comment: Ah, indeed, I missed it’s `props[id]` being `case`d.